# vscode objects passed to the registerHoverProvider. ¿what are yours "keys" and what are they for?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension for visual studio code, I want to show a description of some elements using registerHoverProvider. I have found some examples, but it is not clear to me what the use of each element is and I do not know if there are others. For example:

```
"format": {
    "prefix": "format",
    "body": "format($1)",
    "text": "format()",
    "description":
        "filter formats a given string by replacing the placeholders (placeholders follows the sprintf notation)",
    "example":
        "{% set foo = \"foo\" %}\n{{ \"I like %s and %s.\"| format(foo, \"bar\") }}\n\n{# outputs I like foo and bar #}"
}
```

What are the uses of: prefix, body, and text; and when to use each one